# Bartik's code - manage logo and favicon

Tags: theming

I want upload an image for my theme, like the logo or favicon with bartik (or other theme).
Where's the code for doing that with bartik ? (it's not in bartik/theme-settings)

In fact, i want this features : The user choose his background like the logo

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to show the logo or the screenshot of the theme in your drupal site, just replace your own images with the logo.png or screenshot.png in yoursite/themes/bartik/, remember you have to name them 'logo.png' or 'screenshot.png' exactly.

Not sure if this is what you want. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it's not that.

Where is the code that allow you to create a new input form like logo or favicon : like background or banner for example.

The user choose his background like the logo.

Thanks